# Place content from a clicked element into another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am looking to place content from a child element into another element.

I have a hidden div called "DetailsExpanded" and a series of items called "IconWrapper". On clicking "IconWrapper" I would like to copy the content from that items "ItemDetail" Into "DetailsExpanded" and slide down "DetailsExpanded" with said content

Please see below my html structure.

I have begin on the sliding js but I am a bit out of my depth unfortunately.

```js
$( ".IconWrapper" ).click(function () {
  if ( $( ".DetailsExpanded" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    $( ".DetailsExpanded" ).slideDown( "fast" );
  } else {
    $( ".DetailsExpanded" ).hide();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DetailsExpanded"></div>

        <div class="IconWrapper">
          <div class="ItemDetail">Content to copy</div>
          <div class="Icon icon-icons-d-steps"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="IconWrapper">
          <div class="ItemDetail">Content to copy</div>
          <div class="Icon icon-icons-d-steps"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="IconWrapper">
          <div class="ItemDetail">Content to copy</div>
          <div class="Icon icon-icons-d-steps"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: jQuery's `.html("selector")` function gets the contents of the first element in the set of matched elements http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to take the `.html()` of the clicked element and to set it in your `.DetailsExpanded` element :

```
$(".IconWrapper").on("click", function() {
    var content = $(this).find(".ItemDetail").html();
    $(".DetailsExpanded").html(content);
    $(".DetailsExpanded").slideToggle("fast"); // this replaces slideDown or hide
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! Its very nearly there =] what work thus far, i click the first "IconWrapper" and it slides down with the correct content inside. When i then proceed to click a different "IconWrapper" though, it changes the content and slides up. I added the following line `$(".DetailsExpanded").slideDown("fast");` and the sliding work correctly but the content in being loaded before the slide transition starts, how would i go about loading the content when the slide is closed?

Comment: Managed to get it to work. Thanks for leading my on the right path. Here is what I did `$(".IconWrapper").click(function () {
 var content = $(this).find(".ItemDetail").html();
        if ($(".DetailsExpanded").is(':hidden')){
   $(".DetailsExpanded").html(content);
   $(".DetailsExpanded").slideDown("fast");
   }
        else if ($(".DetailsExpanded").is(':visible')) {
   $(".DetailsExpanded").slideUp("fast", function(){
    $(".DetailsExpanded").html(content);
    $(".DetailsExpanded").slideDown("fast");
   });
   }
});`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( ".IconWrapper" ).click(function () {
  var text = $(this).find('.ItemDetail').text();
  $( ".DetailsExpanded" ).html(text).slideDown( "slow" );  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="DetailsExpanded"></div>

        <div class="IconWrapper">
          <div class="ItemDetail">Content to copy1</div>
          <div class="Icon icon-icons-d-steps"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="IconWrapper">
          <div class="ItemDetail">Content to copy2</div>
          <div class="Icon icon-icons-d-steps"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="IconWrapper">
          <div class="ItemDetail">Content to copy3</div>
          <div class="Icon icon-icons-d-steps"></div>
        </div>
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.IconWrapper').on('click', function(e) {  
      $(".DetailsExpanded").text($(this).text()).slideDown();
   });
});
```